# How do I position an Ionic datetime picker to the top of the screen?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am having trouble positioning this picker at the top of the screen. I have tried overriding many css properties with no success.

I am unable to override the required classes. .sc-ion-picker-md-h

```
  <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="custom">
          <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-menu-toggle><ion-icon name="menu-outline" style="font-size: 30px; color: white !important;"></ion-icon>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
          </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Notification Time</ion-label>
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center>
            <ion-datetime display-format="h:mm A" picker-format="h:mm A" value="1990-02-19T07:43Z" style="height: 100% !important;"></ion-datetime>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-content>
```

[image]

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Ionic uses shadow DOM for it's elements so it is completely separated from your css and can't be manipulated. You can only customize it with the properties given by ionic. And as far as i know the datetime component can not be positioned differently

Comment: you can change teh position... it is all just HTML

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it on top by putting this in the theme/variables.css file:

```
/** Ionic CSS Variables **/
.picker-wrapper.sc-ion-picker-md {
  bottom: auto;
  top: 0;
}
```

(I tested using React, but I guess this should work the same way using Angular or pure js)

[image: On top after clicking "Notification time"]

Comment: this on mobile, i was looking for web.